# Replacing an MKAnnotation pin with a dot

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

'Find My Friends' displays purple versions of the user dot instead of pins, how do I do it?

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let reuse = "blip"
    if let annotation = annotation as? MKPointAnnotation {
        let annotationView = hangMap.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuse)
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        return annotationView
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

I'd like to replace every 'pin' that I dequeue as an annotation with the same blue pulsing user location dot.